# Booking mask - Changing the type="date" value to type="text" when submit

Tags: html, forms, date, submit

I'm working on a hotel website and received a code from TravelClick for the booking mask. My client didn't like the "pop up calendar" so I tried implementing a `"type="date"` in the code instead. But when I click submit, it doesn't recognized the date anymore. I think the problem is that before the type value was `"text"` and now it's `"date"`, but how can I change it back to `"text"` without losing the calendar?

---

```
<form action="https://booking.ihotelier.com/istay/istay.jsp" method="get" name="resform" id=resform"">
<input type="hidden" name="HotelID" value="12401" />
<input type="hidden" name="LanguageID" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="Rooms" value="1" /> 

Check-In Date:
<input type="date" name="DateIn" />


Nights:
<select name="Length">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="10">11</option>
<option value="10">12</option>
<option value="10">13</option>
<option value="10">14</option>
</select>

Adults:
<select name="Adults">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

Children:
<select name="Children">
<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<!-- This javascript code populates the Check-In Date field with today's date. It must be located after the form close tag. -->

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function getDateStr() {
    var today = new Date();
    var todayStr = (today.getMonth()+1) + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getFullYear();;
    document.resform.DateIn.value = todayStr;
}
getDateStr();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I just added the form I'm using, that is not working because of the " type="date" "

Comment: I found an alternative! I used "zebra datepicker" and now everything works fine!! yeah